# parallax animation is not working smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm working on this website
http://1ne-studio.com/test2/

id : test　
pass : 2015

and I have this full screen vertical slider so that website 
works as parallax.

[This is the plugin that I used for this vertical slider - FSVS.JS](http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll)
On their demo all the scrolling movements are smooth, but on my site
when you scroll back to top, every scroll has little glitch where the scrolling animation is smooth all the way to the end.(it has little...weird sudden move animation at the end of scrolling...)

This is the screencapture of my problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgAhyONH0rM

What could be causing this? and how could I fix this..?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What browser are you using ? No problem on `Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m`

Comment: @EdenSource chrome 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) is what i'm using.
This is the screen capture of my animation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgAhyONH0rM

Comment: I've got the bug, however we won't do the job for you: try to reproduce that in a minimal scenario so we can identify the bug. In fact, you'll probably find it by yourself while doing that.

Comment: @floribon Thank you for the advise. I solved the animation problem! Now what I got this problem where I can not see the vertical slides that are supposed to fade-In when you scroll down.